# What is the significance with so many teeth in the movie Triple 9?

Tags: plot-explanation, triple-9

In the movie *Triple 9*, one henchman shows their boss woman a bag of pulled out teeth before the boss woman tosses the teeth into a car's trunk with two tied up people.

What message does the scene carry?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was shown to give proof that they were taken from the two people tied up in the car.

> This is the bag of teeth shown to Kate Winslet as proof that they were taken from the 2 victims seen in the trunk of the Russian mobs car. The bloodied faux teeth are made of resin and are so detailed some even have gold fillings and crowns!!
>
> <sub>[Reference](https://www.yourprops.com/Russian-Mob-victims-teeth-original-movie-prop-Triple-9-2016-YP805064.html)</sub>